# Is ‘when regarding’ in this sentence a preposition, meaning on the subject of/ in respect to, or a verb meaning thinking of/considering?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositional-phrases, present-participles, adverbials

> A recent troubling MIT study, revealed that fake news diffused significantly farther, faster, deeper and more broadly than the truth, with the effect even more pronounced **when regarding** political news as opposed to reporting on natural disasters, finance or science.

Comment: The comma is off there. A recent troubling MIT study revealed etc. Also, "when regarding" ain't great. "when it regards" would be more elegant.

Comment: It's a prepositional phrase. It narrows the type of fake news.

Comment: I think *when regarding* could be replace here by *in*, with adjustment to the rest of the sentence.